# Frontend Deployment Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined with Vite, Chat Engine's and WebSocket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, deployment, build

I'm encountering an issue with my real-time chat application built using Chat Engine. I deployed it on Render.com. The problem is that while the frontend works perfectly on my local system, it fails to work after deployment.

The browser console displays an error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Upon investigating, I found that the issue lies in the use of require, which is not recognized by the browser.

the error

```js
require("websocket").w3cwebsocket;
var Fw = require("websocket").w3cwebsocket
```

I'm using Vite for the frontend. Here are the relevant links:

Live deployment: [live](https://justchat-5uc9.onrender.com/)

GitHub repository:  [repo](https://github.com/0plaze0/justChat)

tutorial: [link](https://blog.chatengine.io/fullstack-chat/nodejs-reactjs)

Any insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: one usually "builds" a project that uses a build tool ... like vite ...

Comment: sorry, I didn't know, I am new to web development. can you help help with this?

Comment: did you `vite build` and deploy the result? looks like you did (now that I checked the live site)

Comment: I'm surprised you don't have `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` though

Comment: Initially, I had it , but later I decided to remove it because I believed that the issue lay with the 'type: module' configuration, causing 'require' not to function as it does in Node.js.

Comment: Do you get *The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.* warning when building

Comment: the I am using es6 in the whole project but the web socket somehow uses the cjs while building the project, I think is something to do with the chat engine

Comment: what should I do so that browser I recognize require after the build

Comment: the problem is that `nextjs-websocket` (which is a dependancy of one of your dependancies) is garbage - the esmodules version of the distributed file has a couple of `require` in it - bit sure what you could do about that to be honest - recognising require won't help

Comment: there is nothing I can do about it I guess I have to use a new package btw thanks for your help @JaromandaX

Comment: I may have been a bit harsh - your code runs fine in dev mode ... so there must be something that can be done

Comment: I looked into some article and chatgpt it say there something called browserify which uses require statements in your client-side code. I will try that and let you know

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.